# react native - How can get the list of "dog" from the sqlite table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, react-native, expo

How can i get the list of "dog" from the table "roma"

the table is: "roma"
the field is: "toto"
the content is : `[{"yoga":63,"dog":"BOB22"},{"yoga":22,"dog":"dragon"}]`

so i want to get "BOB22" and "dragon"

Comment: your JSON doesnt look quite right. You have duplicate yoga and dog keys.

Comment: i fix the json u can see

Comment: are you looking for the result as an array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ["BOB22", "dragon"], you can use the [Array.map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) function to select the keys values you wish to add to a new array. In this case, you would want `entry.dog`.

```
  const toto = [
    { yoga: 63, dog: "BOB22" },
    { yoga: 22, dog: "dragon" }
  ];
  const dogs = toto.map((entry) => entry.dog);
  console.log(dogs); // print ["BOB22", "dragon"]
```

For every item "entry" in toto array, Select "dog" from each entry in toto array only, and return a new array containing each "dog" entry into "dogs" array

Comment: so try to help me with my question in this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63352283/react-native-there-is-way-to-view-the-list-of-the-zone-name-into-flatlist-fro

Comment: Use what I have put here to help you out with that question.